# Assigning corresponding color values to final model variables to be graphed in ggplot (with geom_col) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, modeling, colorbrewer

I’m creating a set of geom_col plots to reveal the model building process where different cognitive task variables are arranged by the order in which they decrease the AIC.

Variables are added by the order in which they decrease the AIC, and are only included in the final model if they significantly (LRT) decrease AIC. So there are four separate performance measures: response window, efficiency, consistency, and psychometric threshold. So naturally, there are four final models— response window, efficiency, consistency, and psychometric threshold. (There will actually be eight final models, since these will fall into math and English standardized test DVs).

So I would like each cognitive task variable included in a final model to correspond with a specific color, such that you could visualize the variables which are consistently included in the different performance measure models. Perhaps there is some way with an “ifelse” statement to create that—if this variable, then red…etc.

I get that you could probably create a vector of color values that corresponded to the specific ordering of the included task variables, but I’m trying to elevate my coding here, and while eight graphs might not be that much time, in cases where you had more graphs, that could be quite an investment. There’s also much less of a chance for mistakes.

The date involves 1000 participants and four performance measures (with English and math categories). Below, I've just included math and English efficiency datasets as a minimal reproducible example.

I use the following code to arrange the included task variables by the order in which they decrease AIC, using the following code with R color brewer (variables are just the cognitive task variables, with their corresponding AIC values in another column). (I use my entire code for producing the graphs below, because sometimes people will have useful feedback and offer more efficient methods, but you can disregard the bottom half of it).

Thanks much! Happy Thanksgiving.

```
efficiency.english<-structure(list(variables = structure(c(3L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 2L), .Label = c("Con, Filter", "Con, SAAT, Sustained", "Demographics", 
"SAAT, Impulsive", "STROOP, Congruent", "Tap and Trace, Tap", 
"TASK SWITCH, Stay", "TASK SWITCH, Switch"), class = "factor"), 
    aic = c(28901.0609423639, 28876.584417846, 28870.0889374339, 
    28862.7732527584, 28859.716837592, 28852.6732473908, 28851.1317635441, 
    28853.8500632933)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

efficiency.math <- structure(list(variables = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L
), .Label = c("Con, Box, Feature", "Demographics", "FILTER", 
"SAAT, Sustained", "Tap and Trace, Tap", "TASK SWITCH, Stay"), class = "factor"), 
    aic = c(28900.5294523709, 28885.7432348228, 28877.1589335409, 
    28872.248022988, 28868.3257096905, 28865.1849707033)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

rw.math<- structure(list(variables = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("BOXED, Feature, 4", 
"Demographics", "SAAT, Impulsive", "Tap and Trace", "Tap and Trace, Tap"
), class = "factor"), aic = c(28896.4668953137, 28882.0804928958, 
28875.7128176706, 28873.9645461461, 28872.7298323499)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

```
colourCount = length(unique(efficiency.math$variables))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))
efficiency.math%>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(variables, desc(aic)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = aic - 28850, fill = name))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  cleanup+
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=7, angle=0),
          strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = getPalette(colourCount))+
  theme(legend.position="right")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0))+
  #labs(x = "Cognitive Measures (Efficiency/Consistency)")+
  labs(y = "AIC + 28850")+
  ggtitle("3b: Math, Eff/Con Model")+
  guides(fill = FALSE)+
  set_theme(title.size = .6)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  cleanup

colourCount = length(unique(final.ela.17.18.rem$variables))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(6, "Set1"))

efficiency.english%>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(variables, desc(aic)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = aic - 28825, fill = variables))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  cleanup+
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=7, angle=0),
          strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = getPalette(colourCount))+
  theme(legend.position="right")+
  labs(y = "AIC + 28825")+
  ggtitle("3c: English, Eff/Con Model")+
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  set_theme(title.size = .6)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())+
    cleanup

colourCount = length(unique(rw.math$variables))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))
rw.math%>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(variables, desc(aic)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = aic - 28860, fill= variables))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")+
  labs(x = "Cognitive Measures")+
  labs(y = "AIC + 28,860")+
  ggtitle("3d: Math, RW Model")+
  guides(fill = FALSE)+
   set_theme(title.size = .6)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))+
  cleanup
```

Answer (score 1):

It was not immediately clear to me what the actual programming related question was, but if I gather correctly, it is about how to get consistent colouring for factor-variables across a series of plots, correct?

A side note is that it is quite difficult to find 26 very distinguishable colours, but they do have an alphabet palette in the Polychrome package.

The main thing will be how to set your fill/colour scale in a plot, which would look like this in pseudocode:

```
scale_fill_manual(
      values = setNames(a_colour_vector, all_factor_levels),
      breaks = all_ordered_factor_levels_to_be_displayed,
      limits = all_ordered_factor_levels_to_be_displayed)
    )
```

And an example with the vectors you provided below:

```r
library(Polychrome)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Data from question
response_window <- c("T", "A", "G", "C")
efficiency <- c("R", "A", "M", "T", "E", "L")
consistency <- c("S", "M", "W", "A", "L", "F")
psychometric_threshold <- c("S", "C", "H", "I", "D")

# Format data as data.frame
df <- rbind.data.frame(
  cbind(name = "response_window", var = response_window),
  cbind(name = "efficiency", var = efficiency),
  cbind(name = "consistency", var = consistency),
  cbind(name = "psychometric_threshold", var = psychometric_threshold)
)

# Generate some value to substitute for AIC
df$value <- rpois(nrow(df), 5)

# Some ordering of the variables, for example random
# in real case probably AIC related ordering
unique_var <- unique(df$var)
df$var <- factor(df$var, levels = sample(unique_var))

# Loop over name, create plot for each name
plotlist <- lapply(split(df, df$name), function(dat) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(var, value, fill = var)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    scale_fill_manual(
      values = setNames(alphabet.colors(), LETTERS),
      breaks = levels(dat$var),
      limits = levels(dat$var)
    ) +
    coord_flip() +
    ggtitle(dat$name[1])
})

# Combine plots for visualisation purposes
plotlist[[1]] + plotlist[[2]] + plotlist[[3]] + plotlist[[4]] + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What the plots exactly look like might not reflect your use case, but you can see that the colouring is consistent across plots.

EDIT: After updating the question, my recommendation would be to do the following:

```
# Put data in list
data_list <- list(
  efficiency_math = efficiency.math,
  efficiency_english = efficiency.english,
  rw_math = rw.math
)

# Edit some metadata
all_levels <- unique(unlist(lapply(data_list, `[[`, "variables")))
colours <- Polychrome::kelly.colors(length(all_levels))
colours <- setNames(colours, all_levels)
titles <- c("3b: Math, Eff/Con Model", "3c: English, Eff/Con Model", "Cognitive Measures")

# Loop over the data
plot_list <- mapply(function(df, title) {
  df$name <- fct_reorder(df$name, desc(df$aic))

  ggplot(df, aes(name, aic, fill = name)) +
    geom_col(colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(
      values = colours
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = range(df$aic),
                       oob = function(x, ...) x,
                       expand = c(0.2, 0)) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_classic() +
    ggtitle(title)
}, df = data_list, title = titles, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Which yields the following:

```
plot_list[[1]]
```

[image]

The reason I went with the adjusted y-scale instead of the 'AIC - 28850' approach, is so that you can spare the observer of your plot the mental mathematics of considering the offset, if the values are already in raw AIC space. It also saves you having to consider an appropriate offset for each plot.

Here is a variation that includes an offset argument:

```
plot_list <- mapply(
  function(df, title, offset) {
    df$name <- fct_reorder(df$name, desc(df$aic))

    ggplot(df, aes(name, aic - offset, fill = name)) +
      geom_col(colour = "black") +
      scale_fill_manual(
        values = colours
      ) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = paste0("AIC + ", offset)) +
      coord_flip() +
      theme_classic() +
      ggtitle(title)
  }, 
  df = data_list, 
  title = titles, 
  offset = c(28850, 28825, 28860),
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
)
```

The plots are still editable, so you could give plot-specific details like below:

```
plot_list[[3]] + labs(x = "Cognitive Measures")
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! "consistent colouring for factor-variables across a series of plots"--this is much more succinct...wasn't sure of how to phrase. Good to know about polychrome package. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow-up question: there would be no way of executing this without combining variables and observations into the same dataset?

Comment: Sorry--I see now where I could've been clearer in my question and have edited my question to reflect that. The above does work, however, the issue is that the total AICs land somewhere around 30,000 and thus, the final task variable AIC values in the graphs are relatively indistinguishable. Perhaps there might be a way to individualize the graphs after applying your patchwork package; or perhaps the edits to my question might provide a better idea of the differences between graphs.

Comment: Right, so if I understand correctly; (1) you'd want to derive the plots programatically without having to combine all data first; (2) You want a sensible axis for the AICs that vary a relatively small amount around a large number and (3) get the output per individual plot? It can be done, but just want to make sure before I make some nonsensical edits to the proposed answer.

Comment: 1) Yes, that is correct. 2) Ideally, I want to be able to alter individual plots given the AIC output (for instance, I could put something like "y = value - 29000" into ggplot(aes()), but really, I want to be able to do this individually per plot. 3) Not sure exactly how this third one differs from 2, but perhaps some additional information may be helpful: I can use fig.hold and fig.align commands in Rmarkdown to gather everything into one figure, so it's fine that the output is five separate plots (glad to know about the patchwork package and "collect" function though).

Comment: Yes, that looks perfect! The only issue is that when I run the code I get this error: "Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector or numeric vector)." Thanks for providing both the offset and the continuous scale. I agree with your logic re using a continuous scale.

Comment: Have you got any clue where in the code this error would occur?